# How to find out if a request is an ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, request

**I try to find out if a request to a PHP file is sent by ajax or not.**

I googled it and read a whole a bunch of articles that suggest following method:

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {     
    echo 'This is an ajax request!';   
    exit;
}
echo 'This is not an ajax request!';
```

But my server doesn't have this variable: `Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH ...`

Thats how I make the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://URL/test.php',
    complete: function(res) {
        console.log(res.responseText);
    }
});
```

I'm making that call from a different url, so I've set `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

I have discovered one difference in `$_SERVER` though:

Ajax request: `$_SERVER[HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*`

No Ajax request: `$_SERVER[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

So my question is, is there a way for me to get `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` into `$_SERVER`?
And if not, is there a proper way to find out if the request is AJAX by using the `$_SERVER[HTTP_ACCEPT]`

Comment: which version are you using jquery ? it should be 1.5 or higher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no 100% way to detect if the request was made via ajax. Even if someone sends header with "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers will send that response
I usually use

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {//Do stuff }
```

and for ajax

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: SomePage.php,
    type: "POST",
    data: {key: value}
});
request.done(function(returnedData) {
    //do done stuff
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    //do fail stuff
});
```

Note:

```
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal. 
(Note that $HTTP_SERVER_VARS and $_SERVER are different variables and that 
PHP handles them as such). Also note that long arrays were removed since PHP 5.4.0 so 
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS doesn't exist anymore.
```

So `var_dump($HTTP_SERVER_VARS);` to see if its contained in there, also note that the `$_SERVER` is filled in by the webserver

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the browser, I tested chrome, safari, FF and none of them have that header, I just wonder how other people get the header as it seems many use that technique to look for an ajax request

Comment: What PHP version are you using and What Webserver?

Comment: Is a virtual server with plesk, PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.23

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is provide your own defined variable, and use a command design pattern to test the outcome for instance:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://URL/test.php',
   data: {action: "ajax_request"},
   complete: function(res) {
   console.log(res.responseText);
 }
 });
```

and the php test:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ($action) {
         case 'ajax_request' : echo 'This is an ajax request!';
        break;

   }
}
else
  echo 'This is not an ajax request!';
```

try this also

```
 while(true)
 {
     ......
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
       echo 'This is an ajax request!';
       return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
     else if(window.ActiveXObject)// for internet explorer
    {
         echo 'This is an ajax request'!;
         return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
       echo 'This is not an ajax request!';
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that I want other users to send the ajax request and therefore I don't know know how they will send it.